# Postpending a string to filename (using pathlib Path)

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, pathlib

I frequently want to postpend a string to a filename, while preserving the extension.

It seems cumbersome to define a function to postpend a string. For example (using pathlib's Path):

```py
from pathlib import Path

def postpend(filename, string):
    filepath = Path(filename)
    return filepath.parent / (filepath.stem + string + filepath.suffix)
```

Is there a built-in function that does this for me?  Is there a better way?

Comment: I don't think there's already a built-in function that does what you want, and I happen to think that your code is not cumbersome and is as elegant and readable as it can be already.

Comment: Ok I see, I don't believe it's pathlibs job to modify strings, it strictly deals with file paths. So in that case what you are doing is fine.

Comment: Though there is a rename function I was not aware of Path.rename(target), not sure if that helps you. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Comment: What do you want returned a `Path` or a `string`?

Comment: Not built-in but simpler than how you do it: `filepath.with_stem(filepath.stem + string)`

Answer (score 0):

If your UseCase is exactly as you have described, then you can use this little trick:

```
filename.replace(".",f"{string}.",1)
```

Since you know that a properly formatted filename will contain exactly one `.`, then replace it with the string + `.`

Comment: @MatthiasArras did you test it? `'nope_you_do_not.tar.gz'.replace('.', '--yes-i-do.', 1)`. In this case it works correctly because Felix wisely used the `count` argument of `replace()`. It would fail if you put a path with dots into `filename`. Like: `filename='path.with.dots/file.tar.gz'`

Comment: I did not test it. Cool that it works nonetheless. Felix's last sentence is misleading then. I deleted my comment, as itself now was misleading.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to return a `string`, you can do:

```
from pathlib import Path

def postpend(filename, string):
    filepath = Path(filename)
    return f"{filepath.parent}\\{filepath.stem}-{string}{filepath.suffix}"
```

If you want to return a `Path` object:

```
from pathlib import Path

def postpend(filename: str, string: str) -> Path:
    filepath = Path(filename)
    return Path(f"{filepath.parent}\\{filepath.stem}-{string}{filepath.suffix}")
```

If the `filename` parameter is a `Path` and you want to return a `Path`, you can do:

```
from pathlib import Path

def postpend(filename : Path, string: str) -> Path :
    return Path(f"{filename.parent}\\{filename.stem}-{string}{filename.suffix}")
```

Comment: The examples show how it should not be done. You are hard-coding the Windows path separator so you are making the code to fail on other platforms. The idea of `pathlib` is to make it possible to write a multi-platform code.